# node.js JSON.parse reviver doesn't report duplicate keys?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, reviver-function

I'm trying to use a JSON parser which will detect and save duplicate keys.  I'm using JSON.parse() in node.js with a reviver, which I am hoping will tell me when I'm getting a duplicate key. However it doesn't. Is there another way?  Is there a better JSON parser which handles duplicate keys in a reviver or other argument?

```
"use strict";

try {
    var content = '{"value": "a", "value": "b", "value": "c" }';
    console.log(content);
    var parsed = JSON.parse(content, function(k, v) {
        console.log(k+"="+JSON.stringify(v));
        return v;
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Output is:

```
{"value": "a", "value": "b", "value": "c" }
value="c"
={"value":"c"}
```

Comment: Do you want to discuss duplicate keys in JSON?   Go here:https://esdiscuss.org/topic/json-duplicate-keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`JSON.parse()` parses the string the same way whether or not you provide a reviver function](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/9116b240c924d37627313416b7ee038d0580afbc/deps/v8/src/json.js#L42) (in other words, it does not switch to a "streaming parser" when a `reviver` is passed in). Providing a `reviver` function is just a convenience so as not to have to write the necessary loops yourself.

There *are* some streaming JSON parsers on npm, for example: [clarinet](https://github.com/dscape/clarinet), [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream), and [oboe](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js). Here's a little test for those 3:

```
var clarinet = require('clarinet').parser();
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream').parse('*', function (value, path) {
  return { key: path[path.length - 1], value: value, path: path }
});
var rs = new (require('stream').Readable)();
rs._read = function(n) {};
var oboe = require('oboe')(rs);

var content = '{"value": "a", "value": "b", "value": "c" }';

clarinet.onopenobject = clarinet.onkey = function(k) {
  console.log('clarinet key =', k);
};
clarinet.onvalue = function(v) {
  console.log('clarinet value =', v);
};
clarinet.write(content).close();

JSONStream.on('data', function(d) {
  console.log('JSONStream data:', arguments);
}).end(content);

oboe.on('node:*', function(n) {
  console.log('oboe node:', arguments);
});
rs.push(content);
rs.push(null);

// output:
// clarinet key = value
// clarinet value = a
// clarinet key = value
// clarinet value = b
// clarinet key = value
// clarinet value = c
// JSONStream data: { '0': { key: 'value', value: 'a', path: [ 'value' ] } }
// JSONStream data: { '0': { key: 'value', value: 'b', path: [ 'value' ] } }
// JSONStream data: { '0': { key: 'value', value: 'c', path: [ 'value' ] } }
// oboe node: { '0': 'a', '1': [ 'value' ], '2': [ { value: 'a' }, 'a' ] }
// oboe node: { '0': 'b', '1': [ 'value' ], '2': [ { value: 'b' }, 'b' ] }
// oboe node: { '0': 'c', '1': [ 'value' ], '2': [ { value: 'c' }, 'c' ] }
// oboe node: { '0': { value: 'c' }, '1': [], '2': [ { value: 'c' } ] }
```

Comment: Is there another parser available for JavaScript?

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't see why you would want to handle duplicate keys in a JSON object, just fix what you're sending instead since it is not valid JSON.

Comment: I know it's not valid JavaScript.  It's acceptable JSON, by some parties.  I am desperately arguing against it, but my words aren't getting across.  I need better words.

Comment: Looking at the output of oboe on a deeply nested, semi-structured document makes me want to throw up.  Ugh.  Back to the standards body.