# How can I re-name duplicate keys in a large JSON file?

Tags: javascript, parsing, steam, jsonstream

I have a large file following this format. Originally I tried parsing this in javascript with JSONStream and ran into some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58227636/how-can-i-parse-a-large-json-file-with-repeating-values-in-javascript). I've been trying to figure out a way to change the duplicate keys so that I can parse this more easily. For example: Instead of `content` each would have a counter appended - `content-1`, `content-2`. This is a very large file so I cannot do it manually, any suggestions on how I can do this or restructure with js would be greatly appreciated!

```
{
    "Test": {
        "id": 3454534344334554345434,
        "details": {
            "text": "78679786787"
        },
        "content": {
            "text": 567566767656776
        },
        "content": {
            "text": 567566767656776
        },
        "content": {
            "text": 567566767656776
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't accept "write your own parser" (like in the other post comments) so I guess that you are asking for a tool or something like that (also like you done in your other post comments). That's out of StackOverflow scope. It seems that the only answer here is "write a parser".

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález yes I understand that is a solution but I'm unable to do that in regards to this specific task so I'm curious if anyone has accomplished the above before.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Writing a custom parser isn't really necessary here.  The parser he's using is fine.  I'd write an answer myself, but I don't really get what the problem is with the data he's getting from JSONStream in the first place.  The data seems fine to me.

Comment: Oh, I see. What I can think of, to make it easy, is to search for strings between double quotes and followed by `:`, so you get all the keys. Then you check for duplicates and rename them. This will find duplicates all around the JSON actually, but whatever.

Comment: @Brad I'm unable to get the duplicate key data. If I can make the keys non-duplicates It won't be an issue to use JSONStream. With JSONStream I only get one of the `content` values

Comment: @Brad Hm, if JSONStream returns data on each key/value pair, then it could work. I thought that it don't made that as the OP had problems with it (never used it). Also interested in your reply xD

Comment: @BluLotus, can you use another language than Javascript outside, just to parse the file, as AWK? with this is juts one line..

Comment: @BluLotus Oh, I think I understand now... the data you're showing is what you're putting in, not what you're getting out?  I thought from your original question that the streaming parser was handling your duplicate key names just fine.

Comment: @Brad yea thats what's going in

Comment: Looking at [JSONStream source code](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream/blob/master/index.js), sure is pretty easy to get around that and receive duplicates (250 lines of code only). Is going to be a bit of try/error work, but debugging step by step should be easy to achieve. TIP: There's a `setHeaderFooter` which seems to create the object that is later streamed. Simply fiddle around that, `hasOwnProperty` and such.

Comment: Check out this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28641538/362536  Try switching to Oboe.

Comment: @Brad thanks, I'm going to check this out

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a `Javascript` question, but I understand you need to load the file in the system and that is a big file.

For this issue, you can use [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) if you are able to use another language outside javascript to parse the file. AWK can be executed under linux, windows bash, etc.

Here is the code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0}/"content"/{a++;gsub("content","content-"a,$0); print $0}!/"content"/{print $0}' file.json
    {
        "Test": {
            "id": 3454534344334554345434,
            "details": {
                "text": "78679786787"
            },
            "content-1": {
            "content-1": {
                "text": 567566767656776
            },
            "content-2": {
            "content-2": {
                "text": 567566767656776
            },
            "content-3": {
            "content-3": {
                "text": 567566767656776
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, nice point. If you still want JavaScript you can run that and then parse the output. Or even better, use this pure JavaScript AWK library: https://github.com/agordon/webawk If that's the way for AWK to work, I'm sure the JavaScript implementation will do it that way also. EDIT: Oh, the problem is that you are looking exactly for "content". Will not detect duplicates automatically. The same thing can be achieved with an easy regex then.

Comment: Nice point. didn't know about this lib!! seems to be a good option for those formatting mind-puzzles...

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I've tried looking for a regex I could use in text wrangler but I haven't found any thing that relates to this.

Comment: You need a regex that looks for the word `"content"`, get the matches and replace them with an incremental.

Comment: In awk is done with the command `"a++;gsub("content","content-"a,$0)"` for every line that has the pattern (this is a regex)  `/content/` https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html